# How to define common column names in entity framework 4.4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using `Entity Framework 4.4` with Database First approach. I have a common `column` defined in most of the tables (say; CreateDate).

I don't want to write date filtering queries for each type and trying to avoid `reflection` i tried to define an *interface* `ICreateDate` such as:

```
interface ICreateDate
{
    System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Auto generated class:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// ...
// </auto-generated>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Project.Entity
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class SomeEntityClass
    {        
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Partial class:

```
public partial class SomeEntityClass : ICreateDate { }
```

Code with exception:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    using (ProjectModel pm = new ProjectModel())
    {
        IQueryable<ICreateDate> qry = pm.SomeEntityClass.AsQueryable().Cast<ICreateDate>();
        qry = DateFilter(qry);
    }
}

private IQueryable<ICreateDate> DateFilter(IQueryable<ICreateDate> queryable)
{
    queryable = queryable.Where(q => q.CreateDate >= SomeRandomDate1 && q.CreateDate <= SomeRandomDate2);

    return queryable.OrderByDescending(q => q.CreateDate);
}
```

Where passing a `IQueryable<SomeEntityClass>` came to be a failed attempt with exception message:

> Unable to cast the type 'Project.Entity.SomeEntityClass' to type
>   'Project.Entity.ICreateDate'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

Since *LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types* is reflection the only choice i have?

**Note:** I tried generic method approach as *Erik Philips* [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584600/how-to-define-common-column-names-in-entity-framework-4/21585093#21585093) but same exact error occurs
**Edit:** I figured out Entity Framework version is `4.4`, EF 5.0 added to a .NET 4.0 project i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have an EntityBase class which usually contains an `Id` and a `CreatedOn`.

Then, all your methods that deal with an Entity can access those properties (or if you're in a method that works on *any* entity, just cast to `Method<EntityBase>`)

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class SomeEntity : EntityBase
{
    /*.....*/
}
```

Comment: An `EntityBase` class you defined?

Comment: Literally a standard class which all entities inherit from. Nothing special or magic... I'll add an example

Comment: This worked, thank you. I still couldn't understand what and why is `Method<EntityBase>`

Comment: Sorry, Zefnus - I'm assuming which is never a good thing. I meant something like this... `public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Query) where T : EntityBase {}` - would let you write a generic method that works against any entity (as defined by the type you use) and return a queryable list of those ... `var RecentOrders = Get<Order>(o => o.CreatedOn > ....)`

Answer (score 2):

> Since LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types is reflection the only choice i have?

No.  Database classes are Partial classes so you can define an interface:

```
public interface ICreateDate
{
  DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Have EF create one of your entity objects by code generation, and it should look like:

```
// MyObject.cs
public partial MyObject
{
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Create your own partial class:

```
// MyObjectPartial.cs
public partial MyObject : ICreateDate
{
}
```

Then create a generic method with a where clause:

```
public IQueryable<T> DateFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable) 
  where T : ICreateDate
{ 
  //code
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what im trying. Only difference is the class name MyObject. I will include more of implementation in my question

Comment: +1 Although it should also be mentioned OP's code doesn't work because EF doesn't support interfaces. You method works around that restriction.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Updated question, sorry for late reply but i tried using generic method as you suggested as well. But had the same exception. Can you run this using `Entity Framework 4.4` ?